# NetBeans Platform: How to disable specific options dialog categories?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have to program a fat client using NetBeans Platform and JavaFX 11. One of the requirements is to offer a default and dark theme mode for the whole application and to **remove the option dialog category Keymaps and the sub category Look and Feel inside the Appearance category**. I searched the web for the appropriate API, but found only [an API to add new (sub) categories to the options dialog](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-options.html).
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like often in the Netbeans platform, customization is done by editing a `layer.xml` file, where you can add stuff but also override the global configuration.

If you don't already have one, create a XML Layer file in one of your modules: **right-click menu New > Module Development > XML Layer**.

The file will appear in the **Important Files** folder of the module.

Expand the `Layer.xml` node and you see <**this layer**> and <**this layer in context**>. The first one shows only the changes present in your file. The second one shows the same thing, but in the global context: the changes present in your file appear in bold, and  the rest is the global configuration.

Expand **OptionsDialog**, and if you don't want the General panel, then select General and delete. This will replace the item with a "hidden" instance.

In the tutorial you mention, they use annotation in the code to add an entry in the `layer.xml` file.

You'll see other nodes like **Menu Bar**, where it's the same principle: you can remove unwanted menu entries, or add new ones (directly in the layer.xml, but much preferably using annotations like `ActionReference`).

Comment: Indeed it seems to be the way how customization is done in netbeans platform. It worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness I add the code fragment that solved my problem:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE filesystem PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Filesystem 1.2//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/filesystem-1_2.dtd">
<filesystem>
     <folder name="OptionsDialog">
         <folder name="Appearance">
             <file name="org-netbeans-core-windows-options-LafOptionsPanelController.instance_hidden"/>
         </folder>
         <file name="Keymaps.instance_hidden"/>
     </folder>
</filesystem>
```

The above code inside a `layer.xml` results in
[image]

Comment: From NB 17 or earlier, it looks like the FlatLaf options panel is now provided by FlatLaf and the name is `org-netbeans-swing-laf-flatlaf-FlatLafOptionsPanelController.instance_hidden`