# NetBeans Rich Client Platform: How to disable specific options dialog categories at runtime?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, rcp, netbeans-platform

This is a follow-up question for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690073/netbeans-platform-how-to-disable-specific-options-dialog-categories) question.
Is there a way to enable or disable specific options dialog categories at runtime? For instance, there are custom options panels of A, B, C, X and Y. An admin user should be able to see A, B, C, X and Y: [image: What admin sees]

whereas a standard user should only see A, B, C:
[image: What user sees]

In other words, can "layer.xml" be edited depending on authorization of the selected user?

Editing "layer.xml" works fine when I add the lines below:

```
<filesystem>
    <folder name="OptionsDialog">
        <folder name="X.hidden">
            <file name="X.instance_hidden"/>
        </folder>
        <folder name="Y.hidden">
            <file name="Y.instance_hidden"/>
        </folder>
    </folder>
</filesystem>
```

but I don't want to re-build and run the program to disable X & Y options specific to non-admin user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the Netbeans System FileSystem at runtime: use `FileUtil.getConfigRoot()` to access its root `FileObject`, then you can navigate through the file system and edit files.

Another option is to write a subclass of `MultiFileSystem`.

More information here: https://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/DevFaqDynamicSystemFilesystem.html